# dnu restore command fails on MAC OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: macos, mono, nuget, visual-studio-code, dnu

When I am running the command dnu restore with --no-cache and without --no-cache , I've got the following errors, Note that mono version is 4.2.1.

visual studio code version is 0.10.06

dnvm list  :

Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          darwin
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1    mono                 linux/osx       default

[mono version info dnu command and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI6j9.png)

[continuous of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfCSW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it or the .lock file is referencing an older version of the DNX.

Can you post your project.json file? Does this happen if you create a brand new project?

Comment: Actually I have the same problem in brand new projects too, my project.json file is the one created by yo with aspnet-generator.
Also it works when I'm using CoreCLR but not when the default is mono!!!